# Usar Glide para cargar una imagen que esta guardada en almacenamiento interno

Tags: android-studio, bitmap, android-glide

Estoy tratando de cargar una imagen desde la memoria interna usando la libreria Glide pero parece imposible.

```
imagePath="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg"
```

este es el codigo mas simple pero no funciona.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.foto);
     File imgFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg");
    Glide.with(this).load(imgFile).into(imageView);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el `path` correcto puedes pasarle una instancia URI a Glide:

```
File file = new File(completePath);

Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Glide.with(this).load(imageUri).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes obtener el Uri del path, asegurando que el recurso existe:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg");
Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);

Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageUri)
                    .into(imageView);
```

Es importarte señalar que en versiones posteriores a Android N se debe usar el método `Uri.parse()` en lugar de `Uri.fromFile()`, por lo tanto lo correcto es validar:

```
String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG-20161029-WA0025.jpg";
File imgFile = new  File(filePath);
Uri imageUri = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
          imageUri = Uri.parse(filepath);        
    } else{              
          imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);
    }

//Carga imagen.
Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageUri)
                    .into(imageView);
```